# Syncing Android Studio project with Gradle files

Tags: android, android-studio

I was working on a project, and then I got a prompt to update Android Studio. After I did that, I started getting this error when trying to run my app
[image: Error]

It says

> The project may need to be synced with Gradle files

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

**EDIT**

Starting with [Android Studio 3.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html#3-1-0), you should go to:

`File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

---

**OLD**

Clicking the button 'Sync Project With Gradle Files' should do the trick:

`Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

If that fails, try running 'Rebuild project':

`Build -> Rebuild Project`

Comment: Try running './gradlew clean packageDebug' from the project root.

Comment: Updated to android stuido 2.0 and button is now disabled and solution above does not help

Comment: Unfortunately this option does not exist in Android Studio 2.2.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it still exists for me, i'm running 2.2 preview 3.

Comment: Add shortcut to sync project and run Sync project fast by keyboard shortcut as below:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29642935/4862126

Comment: Works for me too. Android 2.3. Anyone knows what causes this error? I spent at least 1 hour finding out what's wrong with this.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Had to move all the necessary files into a new project. I'm using Android Studio 3.0

Comment: Starting with Android Studio 3.1, the menu path is `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Comment: File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files  DOES NOT EXIST

Comment: For those only using `gradlew` via command line tools run `./gradlew build`

Answer (score 5):

**Old Answer**

When trying to run the application, instead of selecting the directory highlighted here in blue[image]

I selected the subdirectory instead

[image]

and clicked "run".All the issues with Gradle are automatically resolved and the missing apk directory is automatically created.

**New Solution**

The `Sync project with gradle files` button disappeared from Android Studio for a while.Its back and you can find it here:

[image]

hit the button and wait for the task to complete

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem after installing the genymotion (another android amulator) plugin.
A closer inspection reveled that gradle needs SDK tools version 19.1.0 in order to run (I had 19.0.3 previously).

To fix it, I had to edit `build.gradle` and under `android` I changed to: `buildToolsVersion 19.1.0`

Then I had to rebuild again, and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Android Studio 4 developing a Fluter/Dart application. There does not seem to be a Sync project with gradle button or file menu item, there is no clean or rebuild either.

I fixed the problem by removing the .idea folder. The suggestion included removing .gradle as well, but it did not exist.

Comment: For Flutter, you need to open the Android application in your flutter app in a different Android Studio Window to be able to do anything with gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Keys combination:

```
Ctrl + F5
```

Syncs the project with Gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

The gradle versions in android studio and your code is not the same. This is why even after you update the gradle version on android studio, the error still persist.

So, edit the Gradle distribution reference in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle

Answer (score -1):

i had this problem yesterday. can you folow the local path in windows explorer?

```
(C:\users\..\AndroidStudioProjects\SharedPreferencesDemoProject\SharedPreferencesDemo\build\apk\)
```

i had to manually create the 'apk' directory in '\build', then the problem was fixed

Comment: I just created the 'apk' directory in my build directory.It doesn't work.What else did you do after creating this directory?

Comment: the second thing i did was searching for the SharedPreferences-debug-unaligned.apk and placing it manualy in the apk folder using windows search in startmenu.