# How to include dependencies properly in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am following the tutorial - http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/05/how-to-develop-an-android-weather-app-using-weatherlib.html -  to get weather forecast using yahoo weather api. But, unable to resolve errors given in the screenshot. How do I fix it?

[image: cannot resolve err]
[image]

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932793/syncing-android-studio-project-with-gradle-files

Comment: Are you asking how to add dependencies?

Comment: Thanks everyone. everyone is right here :) But once I rebuild it tempororily fixes the problem and again the same error is shown up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply build your project after adding the dependency. It will download all the packages and the IDE will properly recognize them.