# Android Studio how to run gradle sync manually?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, synchronization

I'm debugging Gradle issues in Android Studio and see references to "Run gradle sync", but I'm not sure how to run this command.

**How do I run "Gradle sync" from Android studio or Mac terminal?**

Comment: If you came here for the "...or Mac terminal" you are out of luck. None of these answers are about syncing Android Studio itself from command line.

Comment: See @Cai's answer below

Answer (score 398, accepted):

Android studio should have this button in the toolbar marked "Sync project with Gradle Files"[image]

Or:

[image]

Or on 3.3.1:

[image]

Or in Android Studio Hedgehog with the new UI:
[image]

OR by going to *File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files* from the menubar.

Comment: missing in Adnroid Studio 3.0.1

Comment: @RomanM It's not missing... It moved to "File"... So, it is next to save icon

Comment: I don't see that button in the toolbar or File menu in Android Studio 4.

Comment: I can confirm the sync button appears on the toolbar in Android Studio 4.0.1

Comment: Why this question has so many upvotes if it is not answering OP's question?

Comment: Is there a command that does this function? Can I run `./gradlew <something>`?

Comment: The real question is: why do the people in charge of Android Studio keep *changing* this functionality?  It's clearly a case of fixing something that's not broken.

Comment: @SMBiggs Or better yet, why isn't there a Context Menu option so that we don't have to memorize the iconset each time?

Comment: @NobleUplift  that's even better!  +1

Answer (score 67):

**WARNING**: `--recompile-scripts` command has been deprecated since `gradle`'s version 5.0.
To check your `gradle` version, run `gradle -v`.

```
./gradlew --recompile-scripts
```

it will do a sync without building anything.

---

Alternatively, with command line in your root project

`./gradlew build`

It will sync and build your app, and take longer than just a Gradle sync

To see all available gradle task, use `./gradlew tasks`

---

OR USING THE BUTTON

[image: gradle icon sync]

Comment: Yes but build does more right? What is the difference between sync and build?

Comment: build is a very generic task. it's like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. On Android projects, running the "build" task could take forever!

Comment: I use com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1，and it has no option   --recompile-scripts

Comment: since gradle 5.0, --recompile-scripts has become an unknow command-line option,

Comment: I don't want to `build`, I only want to `sync`, I don't understand why Google would deprecate and remove `--recompile-scripts` without introducing an alternative ...

Answer (score 43):

In Android Studio **3.3** it is here:

[image]

According to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49576954/2914140 in Android Studio **3.1** it is here:

[image]

This command is moved to `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files`.

[image]

Comment: ROFL! I have been looking for 2 days for this button! Thanks!

Comment: @swooby, you are welcome. I also was finding it for some time, even asked a question, and they helped.

Comment: This option appears to no longer exist? https://i.imgur.com/cNFUoxB.png (screenshot just taken, in Android Studio 3.5.3)

Comment: @Venryx, it is strange. I have 3.6.3 and this menu still exists (https://imgur.com/a/F8FCpvk). Anyway, it is better to use a button in the Toolbar.

Comment: It was apparently a problem with some AndroidStudio/Gradle files being outdated. After deleting them and reimporting the project, the option showed up again.

Comment: @Venryx, thanks for the explanation! Sometimes custom buttons disappear from the Toolbar (and then appear again).

Answer (score 25):

Keyboard shortcut lovers can add a shortcut for running gradle sync manually by going to File -> Settings -> Keymap -> Plugins -> Android Support -> Sync Project with gradle files (Right click on it to add keyboard shortcut) -> Apply -> OK and you are done. [image: Gradle Sync keyboard shortcut]Choose any convenient key as your gradle sync shortcut which doesnot conflict with any other shortcut key, (I have choosen Shift + 5 as my gradle sync key), so next when you want to run gradle sync manually just press this keyboard shortcut key.

Comment: it's 'Android Studio->Preferences' for the first two steps on Mac OS X

Comment: _+1_ the best answer to question

Comment: Best answer, No need to find Sync Project icon from similar icons of android studio. Just press Shift+5 and you are done.

Answer (score 14):

I presume it is referring to Tools > Android > "Sync Project with Gradle Files" from the Android Studio main menu.

Answer (score 7):

```
gradle --recompile-scripts
```

seems to do a sync without building anything. 
you can enable automatic building by

```
gradle --recompile-scripts --continuous
```

Please refer the docs for more info:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html

Comment: Also noted here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html

Comment: gradle 5.1.1 do not have option --recompile-scripts

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut (Ubuntu, Windows):

```
Ctrl + F5
```

Will sync the project with Gradle files.

Comment: on MacOS shortcut is not defined, one should assign it. Described below http://stackoverflow.com/a/29642935/1839096

Answer (score 1):

From terminal:

```
gradle prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel
```

NOTE: you can see what android studio is doing by inspecting the "Build" tab. There will be difference windows inside there. One should be "Sync"

Comment: It does something, like downloading the gradle version, but when I open the project in Android Studio afterwards, it still needs to sync.

Answer (score 0):

I think `./gradlew tasks` is same with  `Android studio sync`.  Why?  I will explain it.

I meet a problem when I test jacoco coverage report.  When I run `./gradlew clean :Test:testDebugUnitTest` in command line directly , error appear.

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.2.jar_5bdiis3s7lm1rcnv0gawjjfxc/jacocoagent.jar
```

However, if I click android studio sync firstly , it runs OK.  Because the `build/../jacocoagent.jar` appear naturally.
I dont know why, maybe there is bug in jacoco plugin. Unit I find  running `.gradlew tasks` makes the jar appear as well. So I can get the same result in gralde script.

Besides, `gradle --recompile-scripts` does not work for the problem.

Comment: Hi Victor, I have a trouble may proof you wrong,

Here is what I got, 
I set a configProductID=11111 from my gradle.properties, from my build.gradle, I add "resValue "string". If I do a build clean from ADT, the resource R.string.ProductID can be generated. Then I can do gradlew assembleDebug to build.

Then I change my config name from "ProductID" to "myProductID", I will get error to do 'gradlew tasks', also I can't do 'gradlew clean', all of them just fail.

I am still struggling. As ".\gradlew.bat --recompile-scripts " seems no longer exists?

Answer (score 0):

I have a trouble may proof gradlew clean is not equal to ADT build clean. And Now I am struggling to get it fixed.

Here is what I got:
I set a configProductID=11111 from my gradle.properties, from my build.gradle, I add

```
resValue "string", "ProductID", configProductID
```

If I do a build clean from ADT, the resource R.string.ProductID can be generated. Then I can do bellow command successfully.

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

But, as I am trying to setup build server, I don't want help from ADT IDE, so I need to avoid using ADT build clean. Here comes my problem.
Now I change my resource name from "ProductID" to "myProductID", I do:

```
gradlew clean
```

I get error

```
PS D:\work\wctposdemo> .\gradlew.bat clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\work\wctposdemo\app\build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'D:\work\wctposdemo\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 57
```

If I try with:

```
.\gradlew.bat --recompile-scripts
```

I just get error of

```
Unknown command-line option '--recompile-scripts'.
```

Comment: I've the same error-message some minutes ago: 

> Unsupported class file major version 57

The issue for me was, that gradle doesn't work with current openJdk13 on Linux (I use Manjaro... an Arch-Like Linux).

So to fix this, I've done this: 
I've checked which Java version I've installed at my pc, and choosed the version 8: 

    sudo archlinux-java stauts
    sudo archlinux-java set java-8-openjdk

Maybe this helping you out, even If your system seems to be windows. So try another SDK Version. Maybe it also solve your issue.

Comment: Hi @suther, many thanks for your reply, I have find the root cause and fixed, I don't think it is because of JAVA version. But as I described "gradlew clean" is not equal to "ADT clean". My fix was simply do "gradlew :app:dependencies", this will generate resource IDs from gradle configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut on Windows is `Ctrl + Shift + o`

In the main menu it is under File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

I am using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 0):

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

will sync and download all dependencies when not cached yet, and android studio and intellij idea will follow the thread started by above command

Answer (score -1):

Anyone wants to use command line to sync projects with gradle files, please note:

Since Gradle 5.0,

> The `--recompile-scripts` command-line option has been removed.

- https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html#potential_breaking_changes
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html
- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1425

Comment: That's great, but how about offering the proper alternative.

Comment: Haven't found one, pity