# Android Studio: No build variant found error

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, variant

i am new to android development, i started developing from scratch on a project i bought online, following the documentation, i encountered a error saying **No variants found for 'app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists.**

Here is the build.gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app-10.app"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
// Third Party Libraries
//Glide library for image fetching from the web
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
//Material library for styling blocks
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
// Google Gson
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'
// Android-SpinKit
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'

implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

// gotev/android-upload-service
implementation "net.gotev:uploadservice:3.5.2"

//A fast circular ImageView perfect for profile images
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'

implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'

}
```

Comment: Clean-rebuild at first

Answer (score 81):

I have just solved the same issue like this:

**Tools -> SDK Manager**

Verify that the SDK platform package for **Android 10.0** (the one with **API level 29**, like you defined in your gradle file) is checked.
If not, check it and apply changes. Accept the licence terms, install the package and then **File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files** (or open the project again)

Comment: Installing API level 29 brought the Build Variant view back for me, no idea why it’s not a part of Android Studio

Comment: For some reason, on Android Studio 2022.2.1 Patch 2, this did not work even though it was the correct solution. I had compileSdkVersion 29. In Tools > SDK Manager, I already had this "installed". 

It wasn't until I went into creating a new emulator, that the emulator complained I had no installed SDKs. Once I installed the SDK via Device Manager, my project ran again. So I was missing the SDK, it was just that Tools > SDK Manager was lying to me (or installing it in the wrong place, idk)

Comment: @WillNasby I've found the same behaviour in my Android Studio right now - if you go to the installed SDK window it says they're all installed, yet when I went to the Emulators window it was already complaining of missing API 30. After installing it and checking the other SDKs (from the Emulator window) it was showing a bunch of them missing. The even annoying part is that this error doesn't say which one it's missing for you to only install that one (at least I didn't find any information).

Answer (score 8):

In my case, it is because I add `flavourDimensions` and not adding it to any `productFlavors`

example from my case I have in my `build.gradle` in app level:

`flavorDimensions "stage", "mode"`

and my `productFlavors`:

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "stage"
        //noinspection DevModeObsolete
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
        resConfigs "en", "xxhdpi"
    }
    
    prod {
        dimension "stage"
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionNameSuffix "-prod"
        applicationIdSuffix '.prod'
    }
}
```

As you can see here, I don't use `flavorDimensions` **"mode"** in any of my `productFlavors`'s `dimension`. So, when I try to sync my gradle. It gives me that error.

So my solution here is to remove `"mode"` from `flavorDimensions`

Answer (score 6):

[image]

go to the SDK manager (Ctrl+Shift+A then write SDK manager), install the android version of current project, in this case I installed all the available options starting from 5.0

Answer (score 4):

I replaced from:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

to my Android Studio v3.0.1 in my case:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

but at the end i resolve it by

[image: you need to detect your proper sdk]

you need to detect and set your proper sdk

my sdk is 30.0.2 after i install 29.0.2 this error gone

Answer (score 2):

Might help someone, in my case, I just needed to update Gradle.

A warning popped up on Android Studio, so I updated it, and then worked properly ‍♀️

Answer (score 2):

You may get the "No variants found" error in a project with multiple modules, when build types do not match between modules.

In my case, this happened when trying to add a [macrobenchmark](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/macrobenchmark-intro) to an existing Android project.
Following the instructions in [this document](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/macrobenchmark), I added a new module `macrobenchmark` to the project.
At some point, I misinterpreted the instructions: I added a new build type `benchmark` to the `build.gradle` of module `app`, but did not add the same build type to the `build.gradle` of module `macrobenchmark`.
From then on, any attempt to [sync the project with the gradle files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565263/android-studio-how-to-run-gradle-sync-manually) would fail with the following error message:

> No variants found for 'macrobenchmark'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists.

The solution was simple (but not trivial): bring the build types back in sync. In my case, add the missing build type `benchmark` to the `build.gradle` of module `macrobenchmark`.

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was that I hadn't opened the project at its root folder, I'd opened the "app" folder. Both folders had the gradle icon so it was an easy mistake to make after not having done any Android development for a while.

Answer (score 2):

The Gradle Sync always gives error **No variants found for 'app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists.**

When running `./gradlew build` It gives new error **Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted.** and **build-tool 31.0.0 is missing dx**

So, if the SDK version is 31, that could be the error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68430992 fixed for me. The soln was to rename d8 to dx.

Comment: In my case, the error was completely diferent that what Gradle Sync show to me. ./gradlew build was half life saver (other half have been used to find this solution). thanks (I hate my job)

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle file in dependencies section I changed

```
if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

to

```
if (enableHermes) {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") {
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, after an AGP upgrade, solded it by selecting arm64 in active ABI:[build variant screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCTur.png)

No idea why that was on 'x86' after AGP upgrade.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I change gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-bin.zip
```

build & install success

Answer (score 0):

The **key reason** is that the gradle didn't recognize the **application module** (opposite to library module ect.) due to some errors in the build.gradle.

The **solution** is to find out what errors happened in the project build.gradle file.

1. right click the abnormal module at the Android view.

[image]

2. select the option [open module settings].
3. check whether the module configuration is correct, including compile SDK version \ Build Tools Version \ Source Compatibility \ Target Compatibility.

[image]

4. correct the configuration and manually sync again.
5. ensure the compile SDK version has been downloaded to local from SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, gradle throws such error when you are trying to import the jar file while there is no jar file or the "libs" folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you can check :

1. Check API version required by app and the one that is installed. As stated by others in above answers.
2. If there is any `settings.gradle` file or `build.gradle`, check if that needs any environment variables, if so feed the env variable on your system, or hardcode the env variable in `settings.gradle` file or `build.gradle` in order to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

tested:

- gradle-7.3.3 + AGP-7.2.0: `namespace "com.example.xxx"` required for aar submodule in build.gradle.
- gradle-6.7.1 + AGP-4.1.0: `namespace "com.example.xxx"` should be
  removed from  aar submodule's build.gradle, while `package "com.example.xxx"` should be added to AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score -2):

Try with

```
npm i cordova-android@10.1.1
```