# Android studio error No variants found for 'app'

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I was opening this webview project and met an error immediatly on importing the project.

**No variants found for 'app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists.**

Already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366729/android-studio-no-build-variant-found-error)  and it didn't help. I am new to android, someone please help.

The following is the build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the full project https://github.com/mgks/Kotlin-SmartWebView

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woB39.png)

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64486128/10985475) what you want to look at is the app-level `build.gradle` file (what you have here is the top-level `build.gradle` file). Get the `compileSdkVersion` and use the `SDK Manager` to download the corresponding Android SDK Version.

Example `build.gradle` file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app-10.app"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

In the above example, the `compileSdkVersion` is 29, so the Android SDK version to download (using the `SDK Manager`) would be API level 29.