# Getting this error after installing android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I'm starting my journey to app development but when I tried to install the android studio I get this error and don't have any idea what is this can anyone help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9RAD.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using an incorrect version of `kotlin-gradle-plugin`. Try

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0'
```

or

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0-RC'
```

Refer [Maven Repository page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin) or [Gradle Plugins repository page](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android) for a full list of available versions.

Comment: then how can I sync it again after adding this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565263/android-studio-how-to-run-gradle-sync-manually