# Accidentally include ':app' line deleted in settings.gradle file i cannot sync or run project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

like I said: I accidentally deleted `include ':app'` and i clicked `sync`.

Now i rewrote that line again, there is no `sync` button so for me: everything is lost.

Do i have to start a new project to soleve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

There is **no** `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files and Build -> Rebuild Project`

Comment: what do you mean by **everything is lost** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syncing Android Studio project with Gradle files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932793/syncing-android-studio-project-with-gradle-files)

Comment: İ cannot run the project, in the "android" nothng is shown. when i click run,  it asks me for some configuraitons.

Comment: add your gradle file we would find a problem

Comment: @mawalker , the solutions in that link didnt work for me. İ dont have sync button in tools also.

Comment: [Build] -> [Rebuild Project] just worked for me... I just deleted my `include ':app'` line from settings.gradle and then readded it. and instead of clicking 'sync now' I did above and it worked fine. Perhaps close AS and restart it. might be IDE glitch

Comment: @mawalker there is also no button build -> rebuild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing project and importing project fixed the issue. None of the solutions above worked by the way

Answer (score 1):

1. Close and Re-open the `build.gradle`.
2. **Add back the line you deleted.**
3. If the `Sync` button still does not show, go to the next step. If it shows, just `sync`.
4. Change something randomly in `dependencies`, `build types` or `default` config.
5. Once the `sync` button shows, **revert back the random change**.
6. Press `Sync`.

Also try `File > Invalidate Cache and Restart`

Comment: i am trying step 4 and still nothing is popping up to me saying "sync"

Comment: Change something and revert in app build.gradle

Comment: The problem is in "Android" view of project, there is nothing!!! In project i found build.gradle and trying to rewrite some texts, still no button

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart

Comment: do it ... since this is a new project you dont have much to lose.

Comment: it says "No usage found in the project". So i couldn't do it. I will create a new project probably