# Android is not loading correctly

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have installed Android Studio 2.3.3 with Gradle 4.0.1, and it was working fine, but one day it seems like it is not loading correctly. I build the Gradle, clean and rebuild my projects, and it shows that was build correctly, I can even compile, but everything in the IDE is in red, like it's not loading the libraries. What could it be? Sorry for the short explanation but it's all I have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19933548/3111083 syncing should fix the problem. Try the new solution in that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also rarely happens for me - usually solved by "invalidate caches -> restart"