# "preview unavailabe until after a successful project sync"

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in andriod development. I downloaded the latest visual studio and the preview is now showing because it says "preview unavailabe until after a successful project sync"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syncing Android Studio project with Gradle files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932793/syncing-android-studio-project-with-gradle-files)

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio (unlikely) or Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

File -> Sync with File system :)